# Karbonn A1+ CWM recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, karbonn-a1+

I have a Karbonn a1+ and i have rooted it. I want to install CWM recovery plz tell me the method and files that i require. Also my hardware version is 1.1.0 and software version is 2.0.2. Also is it possible to upgrade my phone to 4.0 i.e ice cream sandwich.

Answer (score 1):

Download CWM here: [http://www.mediafire.com/download/kf88nz9k9adugqa/A1%2B+recovery.img](http://www.mediafire.com/download/kf88nz9k9adugqa/A1++recovery.img)

Download Mobileuncle tool: http://www.mediafire.com/download/lmd4m939ymahddz/Mobile+uncle+tools%281%29.apk

How to install

1. Download Recovery.img and Mobileuncle tool from given links
2. Rename A1+ recovery.img to recovery.img
3. Copy recovery.img to root of your sd card
4. Install mobileuncle tool
5. Open mobileuncle tool. Click flash recovery from sdcard, allow root permission, and click ok. Thats it.

Information found on XDA Forum ([source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=45694085)).

Custom ROMs for the Karbonn A1+ are few, but I found this [XPERIA Rom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=43737940) forum. More can be found elsewhere. Do your research and you'll find some more.